# Invoking a custom function in r for every row of a dataset

Tags: r, apply

I have a custom function that I have built that takes two inputs, does some processing to compute a value and return it.

Now, I want to use specific columns of a dataframe as inputs to this custom function. I want the function to process each row of the dataframe column and compute the corresponding return value. I do not want to use a FOR loop to iterate through each row of the dataframe. I have tried the "apply" function - but, do not seem to have any luck getting it to work.

This is a illustration of what I have outlined above.

```
Myfunction(movie, user)
{
    do some processing with the input values
    return(predict_value)
}

Pred_rating<-apply(Mydataset[,c("Movie_ID","User_ID")],MARGIN = 1,Myfunction)
```

If the computation of the function performed as expected, assuming the `Movie_id` and `User_ID` columns had 5 rows each for example, I would expect the result of  "apply" to be a vector of 5 values; as the apply function has computed a return value for each of row of the input.

**Questions:**

Am I coding the "apply" function correctly?
Is there a different delivered/packaged function I should be using?

Comment: What output are you getting, and how does that differ from what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

If your function support vectorized inputs, you can compute it with the following

```
Pred_rating <- Myfunction(Mydataset$Movie_ID, Mydataset$User_ID)
```

and no need for `for-loop`.

Otherwise I suggest to look into `Map` and `mapply`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7141669/5184851) for details.